# How to check whether Junit is running with JunitRunner or PowermockRunner

Tags: java, junit, powermock

During writing junits to the classes, I got some requirement like executing tests in with different runners like once with JUnitRunner and then with PowermockRunner, so based on that I want to decide whether to skip test or continue. Please could you let me know is there any way to check like this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't. Just. Don't. This is so wrong on so many levels. Write two tests, each with it's own runner and be done with it. If you need to, put code in a shared abstract base test class.

Answer (score 1):

There are several options, but none of them is pretty.

Your best bet would be if either of these runners supported a system property that you can query, but I doubt that.

Failing that, you can either do a class lookup or inspect the stack.

1. Class Lookup

   ```
   boolean isPowerMock = false;
   try{
     Class.forName("fully.qualified.name.of.PowerMockRunner");
     isPowerMock = true;
   }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){}
   ```

Note that this technique may return a false positive if PowerMock is on the class path, but the runner isn't used.

2. Inspect stack

   ```
   boolean isPowerMockRunner = false;
   for (StackTraceElement stackTraceElement : Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()) {
       if(stackTraceElement.getClassName().contains("PowerMockRunner")) {
           isPowerMockRunner = true;
           break;
       }
   }
   ```

Or, Java 8-style:

```
boolean isPowerMock = Arrays.stream(
                                Thread.currentThread()
                                      .getStackTrace()
                             )
                            .anyMatch(
                                elem -> elem.getClassName()
                                            .contains("PowerMockRunner")
                             );
```

Comment: Just I want provide some more details, that is I have created a Junit with @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) @PrepareForTest(classes to be mocked in static way).